# Paint directly on model or redo UV unwrap for new faces

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm new to Blender and not a 3D designer. I'm a photogrammetrist.

I have a very complex mesh that I created with photogrammetry. I used Blender to repair the mesh in places where it did not generate good connections. I'd like to now go back and paint the fixed surfaces with texture I've pulled from the photos.

[image]

The problem is, since I've added new faces, the UV map is scrambled and overlapping my new faces with old texture. It applies the wrong textures to the faces.

[image]

Is there a way (inside or outside of Blender) that I can just paint my texture onto the surfaces or unwrap the new faces without destroying the existing texture?

Comment: You can unwrap untextured mesh parts and position them in empty areas on UV map. On the other hand that should be fixed in your photogrammetry software by assigning colors to vertices in the fixed areas.