# Removing unwanted part from texture file

Tags: texturing, uv

So I made a 3d model from 21 pictures with 123dcatch, I removed the unnecessary parts with blender.
Then I merged the 2 4096x4096 texture with a python script.

But now I have a 8096x8096 file with half of the space being empty and certain part not being used

[image: texture map]

for example I want to remove what I circled in red and move what I circled in blue at it's place.
I also want to crop the texture file.

Is that possible?

Comment: to remove the part just paint  over it,  for placing the uv i think you'll have to do it manually

Comment: Check my answer on a similar question maybe that can help:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28902/sort-out-a-complex-uv-map-for-a-complex-mesh/