# Keep texture and change UVs?

Tags: texturing, uv

I was creating a simple terrain texture, and just used the create simple uvs button. The UV's it created were pretty ugly, but I didn't care, because I was only going to be texture painting directly onto the 3d mesh, and regardless of how nice my UV unwrap was, it still looked fine. For all I cared, it could make each face separate from each other (and that's nearly what it did, even though my object was basically just a plane with a few verts moved around for hills). Now, I want to clean up the UV map a little bit, but I don't want to repaint the texture that I spent an hour or two creating.

Is there any way for me to fix up the UV map while moving the texture along with it, so that the final result looks the same, but it just has a better map?

Comment: Yes, check this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28902/sort-out-a-complex-uv-map-for-a-complex-mesh/28914