# Import Sketchup model/.obj file and bake

Tags: uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have a question about texture atlases. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I imported my model from Sketchup via .obj [image]

It has multiple materials on one mesh. All I'm trying to do is to bake it into a uv map while keeping the uv information. Whenever I bake (I tried cycles and blender render), the tiling goes to shit.

[image]

It does get better when I size up the blank image, but it would have to be insanely huge to match the textures of the original model.
Is there a way in Blender to bake the textures as they appear on the imported model? I have also tried the texture atlas plugin, but I haven't found a tutorial yet that deals with this situation. They all show you how to combine objects with one material each, and they're all either made IN Blender or have simple colors instead of tiled textures. I haven't yet been able to figure it out by myself.
I'v also tried taking screenshots and projecting each side onto it, but it was grueling work with horrid results, so I gave up on that pretty quickly.

I also tried tiling it manually, but it always has some mistakes and it takes ages. The point is: This model is a neat, finished building exactly how I wanted it. I'd like to keep it that way and just give it a texture atlas to get rid of the draw calls in my engine.

Is this even possible? If not, what alternatives do I have if 90% of my models are .skp files. I'd be very glad if someone could help (:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort out a complex UV map for a complex mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28902/sort-out-a-complex-uv-map-for-a-complex-mesh)

Comment: Try to scale up the UV map (as I suppose the textures are seamless)