# Bake texture to new UV map (in Blender 2.91)

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I 3D scanned an object and exported it as an .obj file (including the generated texture), then did some cleanup in Blender 2.91. The UVs were a mess, so I created a new UV map for the object and followed a tutorial to unwrap multiple parts of the model separately. Afterwards I used "Seams From Islands" and unwrapped again, which created UVs that look decent (in my opinion at least).

I then tried to follow [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28914/100690) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15514/100690) answer to get the texture for the new UVs by creating a new image in the "UV Editing" view, keeping it selected with the new UV map active and baking it ("Cycles" render engine, unticked all influences as I only want the original texture without any additional light spots). This (after taking a long time) changed the original texture (instead of the new one) but it's only black "blobs" in the shape of the new UVs with a surrounding transparent area.

On Youtube I found another tutorial that uses nodes in a newer Blender version but there aren't any nodes in my project and when I tried to recreate what the youtuber had (I've never used nodes before), I noticed that the "UV Map" node he uses ([this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html) one) isn't even in the list and the "Map UV" node ([this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/map_uv.html) one) looks completely different.

UV Map node I have:
[image]

UV Map node I need:
[image]

How can I bake the old texture onto the new image, using the new UVs but without using nodes? Is that even possible? If it's not, how do I add the "UV Map" node and what nodes do I need for the original UVs/texture?

Comment: Hi :). Judging by the nodes difference, you opened *Compositor*, but you need the *Shader editor* for baking. Both use nodes, but have different purpose ;)

Comment: I always pressed Shift+F3, which supposedly opens the "node editor". I just also checked the "Shading" tab (at the top) and you're right, there are already nodes there (texture, "Principled BSDF" & "Material Output", no UV one though, do I need that one too?). Thanks! Now I only have to figure out how to actually get it to use the new image with nodes - or do you also happen to know how to do this without nodes (which I'd really prefer)?

Comment: Hi :). You cannot do this outside of shader editor as of now. But no worries, it ain't complicated. Related questions on this site/YT tutorials should help, the process haven't changed in 10 years ;)